# Using cropper.js before Dropzone.js send image to server

Tags: jquery, image, base64, crop, dropzone.js

What I want to do here is before  Dropzone.js send the dropped image to the server, a modal appears with cropper.js (fengyuanchen script) so the user can crop the image, and when image is cropped, send it with Dropzone.js  to the server.

So when i change the image src of #cropbox with the function fileToBase64 and replace the image of the cropper with the function cropper('replace'), it keeps showing default.jpg image, instead of the new one uploaded from the user

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-crop-box">
    <div class="crop-box">
        <img src="default.jpg" alt="Cropbox" id="cropbox">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function fileToBase64(file) {
  var preview = document.querySelector('.crop-box img');
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}

$(function() {
    Dropzone.options.avtDropzone = {
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        paramName: 'file',
        maxFilesize: 2,
        maxFiles: 1,
        thumbnailWidth: 200,
        thumbnailHeight: 200,
        accept: function(file, done) {
            fileToBase64(file); 
            $('#cropbox').cropper('replace', $('#cropbox').attr('src'));
            $('.wrapper-crop-box').fadeIn();
            done();
        },
        init: function() {
            this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                if (this.files[1]!=null){
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $('#cropbox').cropper({
      aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
      resizable: false,
      guides: false,
      dragCrop: false,
      autoCropArea: 0.4,
      checkImageOrigin: false,
      preview: '.avatar'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably don't need it anymore, but I'll just leave it here :)

It was a bit tricky and my solution is probably somehow 'hackish', but it works and you don't have to upload files on server to resize.

I'm also using cropper in a modal window. I wanted to force user to crop image to a certain dimensions before uploading to server.

After you confirm crop in a modal image is instantly uploaded.

```
// transform cropper dataURI output to a Blob which Dropzone accepts
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}

// modal window template
var modalTemplate = '<div class="modal"><!-- bootstrap modal here --></div>';

// initialize dropzone
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(
    "#my-dropzone-container",
    {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        // ..your other parameters..
    }
);

// listen to thumbnail event
myDropzone.on('thumbnail', function (file) {
    // ignore files which were already cropped and re-rendered
    // to prevent infinite loop
    if (file.cropped) {
        return;
    }
    if (file.width < 800) {
        // validate width to prevent too small files to be uploaded
        // .. add some error message here
        return;
    }
    // cache filename to re-assign it to cropped file
    var cachedFilename = file.name;
    // remove not cropped file from dropzone (we will replace it later)
    myDropzone.removeFile(file);

    // dynamically create modals to allow multiple files processing
    var $cropperModal = $(modalTemplate);
    // 'Crop and Upload' button in a modal
    var $uploadCrop = $cropperModal.find('.crop-upload');

    var $img = $('<img />');
    // initialize FileReader which reads uploaded file
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        // add uploaded and read image to modal
        $cropperModal.find('.image-container').html($img);
        $img.attr('src', reader.result);

        // initialize cropper for uploaded image
        $img.cropper({
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            autoCropArea: 1,
            movable: false,
            cropBoxResizable: true,
            minContainerWidth: 850
        });
    };
    // read uploaded file (triggers code above)
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    $cropperModal.modal('show');

    // listener for 'Crop and Upload' button in modal
    $uploadCrop.on('click', function() {
        // get cropped image data
        var blob = $img.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL();
        // transform it to Blob object
        var newFile = dataURItoBlob(blob);
        // set 'cropped to true' (so that we don't get to that listener again)
        newFile.cropped = true;
        // assign original filename
        newFile.name = cachedFilename;

        // add cropped file to dropzone
        myDropzone.addFile(newFile);
        // upload cropped file with dropzone
        myDropzone.processQueue();
        $cropperModal.modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: works amazing..except it's not uploading the cropped image for me but the original :/ put my code in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/CanR/1b9dy5cd/ so every step is or seems fine, only that the end result is not the cropped square but the original

Comment: @CanRau You did `dz.addFile(blob);` while you wanted to add the `newFile` that you set up in the code path. So `dz.addFile(newFile);`

Answer (score 4):

For devs that don't want or can't have the jQuery dependency.

I've recently written an [article on integrating Dropzone with Cropper.js](https://itnext.io/integrating-dropzone-with-javascript-image-cropper-optimise-image-upload-e22b12ac0d8a), it might be useful. See code snippet from the article below.

The HTML

```
<div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></div>
```

The JavaScript

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    url: '/post',
    transformFile: function(file, done) {

        var myDropZone = this;

        // Create the image editor overlay
        var editor = document.createElement('div');
        editor.style.position = 'fixed';
        editor.style.left = 0;
        editor.style.right = 0;
        editor.style.top = 0;
        editor.style.bottom = 0;
        editor.style.zIndex = 9999;
        editor.style.backgroundColor = '#000';

        // Create the confirm button
        var confirm = document.createElement('button');
        confirm.style.position = 'absolute';
        confirm.style.left = '10px';
        confirm.style.top = '10px';
        confirm.style.zIndex = 9999;
        confirm.textContent = 'Confirm';
        confirm.addEventListener('click', function() {

            // Get the canvas with image data from Cropper.js
            var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                width: 256,
                height: 256
            });

            // Turn the canvas into a Blob (file object without a name)
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {

                // Update the image thumbnail with the new image data
                myDropZone.createThumbnail(
                    blob,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailWidth,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailHeight,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailMethod,
                    false, 
                    function(dataURL) {

                        // Update the Dropzone file thumbnail
                        myDropZone.emit('thumbnail', file, dataURL);

                        // Return modified file to dropzone
                        done(blob);
                    }
                );

            });

            // Remove the editor from view
            editor.parentNode.removeChild(editor);

        });
        editor.appendChild(confirm);

        // Load the image
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        editor.appendChild(image);

        // Append the editor to the page
        document.body.appendChild(editor);

        // Create Cropper.js and pass image
        var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            aspectRatio: 1
        });

    }
};
```

A demo of the integration code can be found here:
https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/PXQNGp?editors=0010

Comment: This one is also not uploading the cropped image but the original

Comment: I have find the index and replaced file.. `myDropZone.files[myDropZone.files.indexOf(file)] = newFile;`

Comment: @Sachin It is not working for me. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Mosam what's the issue ? Are you not getting files on server side ?

Comment: Same issue here. Everything looks good in the UI but it uploads the original image, not the cropped one :S

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gist that provides this functionality.

https://gist.github.com/maria-p/8633b51f629ea8dbd27e

```
// transform cropper dataURI output to a Blob which Dropzone accepts
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}

// modal window template
var modalTemplate = '<div class="modal"><!-- bootstrap modal here --></div>';

// initialize dropzone
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(
    "#my-dropzone-container",
    {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        // ..your other parameters..
    }
);

// listen to thumbnail event
myDropzone.on('thumbnail', function (file) {
    // ignore files which were already cropped and re-rendered
    // to prevent infinite loop
    if (file.cropped) {
        return;
    }
    if (file.width < 800) {
        // validate width to prevent too small files to be uploaded
        // .. add some error message here
        return;
    }
    // cache filename to re-assign it to cropped file
    var cachedFilename = file.name;
    // remove not cropped file from dropzone (we will replace it later)
    myDropzone.removeFile(file);

    // dynamically create modals to allow multiple files processing
    var $cropperModal = $(modalTemplate);
    // 'Crop and Upload' button in a modal
    var $uploadCrop = $cropperModal.find('.crop-upload');

    var $img = $('<img />');
    // initialize FileReader which reads uploaded file
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        // add uploaded and read image to modal
        $cropperModal.find('.image-container').html($img);
        $img.attr('src', reader.result);

        // initialize cropper for uploaded image
        $img.cropper({
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            autoCropArea: 1,
            movable: false,
            cropBoxResizable: true,
            minContainerWidth: 850
        });
    };
    // read uploaded file (triggers code above)
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    $cropperModal.modal('show');

    // listener for 'Crop and Upload' button in modal
    $uploadCrop.on('click', function() {
        // get cropped image data
        var blob = $img.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL();
        // transform it to Blob object
        var newFile = dataURItoBlob(blob);
        // set 'cropped to true' (so that we don't get to that listener again)
        newFile.cropped = true;
        // assign original filename
        newFile.name = cachedFilename;

        // add cropped file to dropzone
        myDropzone.addFile(newFile);
        // upload cropped file with dropzone
        myDropzone.processQueue();
        $cropperModal.modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Note, I am not the author.

Answer (score -3):

I've done it using dropzone.js and cropper.js inside angular.js module. maybe it can help someone.

```
[http://pastebin.com/4miiWbyZ][1] - angularjs
[http://pastebin.com/1kBkvWt8][2] - dropzone.html
[http://pastebin.com/jmDdNWFf][3] - cropper.html
```